# Can I pursue a Master's in the USA in software engineering after a Bachelor's in IT in Nepal?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, computer-science

Can I do a Master's in software engineering in the USA, because I've done a Bachelor's in information technology in Nepal? 
Software engineering and information technology are different majors, so will it cause any problem to do a Master's in software engineering? So, please help me out here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of your other question [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41072/masters-in-software-engennering-with-different-bachelor-major)

Comment: I closed the other one instead, because this copy has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**You can apply for the master degree in computer engineering with a bachelor in IT.** However number of things here:

1. You will pay a lot of money for a master degree in the US. So what is the game plan here?
2. If you get into a true to the core engineering course, you will have a hard time, as they will focus on the practical aspects of computer science and it might be very hard for you to complete your degree on time. For example, you might see a typical student can create a simple compiler in a 5 hours sitting, while it might take you three months to get to that point.
3. If you want to continue to the Ph.D. program after your Msc, you will still have some problems, because your marks might not be good based on the second point.
4. If you want to start a company after Msc, I would suggest to think about it very carefully as Msc, with huge tuition fee, might not be a good choice.